# Javascript html editor cursor focus following mouse

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I use a dhtml (midas) editor as a html editor in my web application, what I want to do is get a focused cursor in this html editor follow the mouse, is there a way to do that?

Added Example:
I want cursor in textarea follow the mouse so if you have a big text in your textarea and you are going over it with mouse, cursor (text cursor) should follow the mouse, like this:

"This is an ex|ample text" - if mouse is over "example" word and between x and a, text cursor (|) should be focused there but when I move mouse on for example "text" cursor | should be between letters where mouse is currently located.

Comment: What is the id/name of your html editor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution using Ext.util.TextMetrics, first I get position of every character in editor, then I compare that to mouse cursor position and then update midas selection based on given character from charNum array

```
htmlEditor.getEl().on('mousemove', function(e)
{   
    var charNum = {},
        text = htmlEditor.getValue(),
        fWidth = htmlEditor.getWidth();

    var textMetrics = new Ext.util.TextMetrics(htmlEditor.getEl(), htmlEditor.getWidth());

    for(var n=0;n<text.length;n++)
    {
        var dat = text.substring(0, n)
        var width = textMetrics.getWidth(dat);
        var height = textMetrics.getHeight(dat);

        if(width > fWidth)
        {
            var mult = Math.ceil(width/fWidth)
            var width = width % fWidth;
            height = height*mult;
        }

        charNum[n] = [width, height];
    }

    //console.log("charNum: "+charNum.toSource());

    var mX = e.getX();
    var mY = e.getY();

    var cXY = htmlEditor.getEl().getXY();
    var cX = cXY[0];
    var cY = cXY[1];                    

    var x = mX-cX-20;
    var y = mY-cY;

    //console.log("fin xy: "+x+' '+y);

    var n = -1;
    var z = 0;
    for(key in charNum)
    {
        if(charNum[key][0] > x && charNum[key][1] > y) 
        {
            n = key-1;
            break;
        }
        n++;
        z++;
    }

    if(x < 0 && y < 14) n = -1; 


    if(n == (z-1) && n != -1)
    {
        n++;
    }

    var selection = htmlEditor.win.getSelection();

    range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.selectNodeContents(htmlEditor.getEditorBody());
    range.collapse(true);
    for(var x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        selection.modify("move", "forward", "character");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Activates ExtJs HtmlEditor textarea when it is loaded](http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/activates-extjs-htmleditor-textarea-when-it-is-loaded/) and [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-focus), the official docs says:

```
Note: The focus/blur and validation marking functionality inherited from Ext.form.Field is NOT
supported by this editor.
```

Comment: I added example of what I want to do, focusing the field is not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the solution of @dfilkovi, but albeit it can be correct, bear in mind that any solution binding an event to mousemove will mostly certain cause a huge overhead on cpu.

To alleviate this symptom, you could unbind the listener first thing at the handler and then set a timeout to bind it after a few millisecs; something like:

```
// assume HandleOriginal as the original function declared by @dfilkovi

// attach the listener
startListener();

// functions
function startListener() {
    htmlEditor.getEl().on('mousemove', HandleAndWait);
}

function stopListener() {
    // maybe this is not the right syntax
    htmlEditor.getEl().on('mousemove', null);
}

function HandleAndWait(e) {
    var C_SLEEP = 50;
    stopListener();

    try { HandleOriginal(e); }
    finally { window.setTimeout(startListener, C_SLEEP); }

}
```

You can, then, fine tune the value of `C_SLEEP` to the best user experience.